# Azure Notification Hub view registrations with tags

Tags: azure, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, azure-mobile-services, azure-notificationhub

I am using `Azure Notification Hub` to send out push notifications to several mobile platforms.

By registering for the `Mobile Service` I specify several tags for the push notifications of the `Notification Hub`. My question is how can I view all registrations and all tags that have been registered?

I can't find anything in the management portal or in Visual Studio. Is there a tool that can be used to show all registrations for a `Notification Hub`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For programmatic access, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790624.aspx can be used to export registrations and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223270.aspx will allow you to read all registrations in your hub. To see registrations in Visual Studio, follow the "verify registrations" section in https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-diagnosing/. Hope this helps!

Comment: Right what I was looking for! Thx